# Cannot download WSO2 DSS 3.0.1 using WGET

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I tried to download WSO2 Data Services Server (DSS) 3.0.1 following the instructions in:
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/Obtaining+the+Product

It's said there to use:

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" http://dist.wso2.org/products/data-services-server/3.0.1/wso2dss-3.0.1.zip
```

I googled and tried --user-agent="Mozilla" and other things but none worked. I signed up and tried to use the --user=user and --password=pass but no luck either.

I use RedHat linux server. Does anybody has similar situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need an extra referer parameter to make it work:

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download" http://dist.wso2.org/products/data-services-server/3.0.1/wso2dss-3.0.1.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download WSO2 DSS 3.0.1 from [here](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server).

Answer (score 0):

Download API Manager with this link:

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download" https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/api-manager/2.1.0/wso2am-2.1.0.zip
```